# How to init a UICollectionView and then add layout constraint to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout, custom-keyboard

I have noticed that there is only one method to init a `UICollectionView`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
         collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

But right now, I want to use auto layout to position this collection view. But it's already given a frame. Will it still work if I add layout constraint to it?

I am adding this collection view as a subview of custom keyboard which has a view controller subclass from `UIInputViewController`. I NSLog custom keyboard view's frame. I am getting frame: {0,0},{0,0} and bounds: {0, -30},{0,30}. Why I am getting these values? I don't understand. Since these values are not valid, so if I assign the self.bounds to collection view initialization. It's not going to work. So the question is, how to add a `UICollectionView` into custom keyboard, and position it correctly?

Comment: Do you add the constraints by code?

Comment: And you add it in updateConstraints with  [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];?

Comment: @Horst No. I am using [self.view addConstraints:]

Comment: Try to call it in updateConstraints and call [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints] to fire updateConstraints

Comment: @Horst But I am in a UIViewController. updateConstraints is a UIView function. How about updateViewConstraints. Will it work as well?